# WiX - How to prevent bootstrapper from installing itself; only install chained packages

Tags: .net, wix, wix3.7, bootstrapper, burn

I have a bundle that I hide from Programs and Features:

```
<Bundle DisableRemove="yes" DisableModify="yes" ...
```

It installs the following as part of its `Chain`:

```
<ExePackage Permanent="yes" ...
<MsiPackage Visible="yes" DisplayInternalUI="yes" ...
```

The `ExePackage` is permanent, but the `MsiPackage` is not.

**Here's the problem**:

After I run the bootstrapper and have installed the bundle, if I uninstall the `MsiPackage` from Programs and Features, and then run my bootstrapper again, it will show an *Uninstall* option...despite the fact that all non-permanent packages have been removed. Why is that? How can I prevent this? Ideally, when I launch the bootstrapper again, it should go straight to a UI with options to *Install* the bundle again without requiring an uninstall of the bootstrapper.

Answer (score 0):

> You can set Visible="yes" on an MsiPackage to have it shown in
>   Programs and Features.
>
> You can hide a Bundle from Programs and Features by setting
>   DisableRemove="yes" DisableModify="yes".

More detail, check this:
[Wixtool Burn install and uninstall 2 separated MSIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27145554/wixtool-burn-install-and-uninstall-2-separated-msis?rq=1)

Comment: This will only hide the bootstrapper from ARP, but it will still be "installed".