# Wixtool Burn install and uninstall 2 separated MSIs

Tags: wix, burn

I have created a Wix custom bootstrapper application and bundle file using Wix 3.8. My Chain tag looks like:

```
<Chain>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx451Redist"/>
      <MsiPackage Id="MSI1" SourceFile="$(var.MSI1Path)"/>
      <MsiPackage Id="MSI2" SourceFile="$(var.MSI2Path)"/>
</Chain>
```

The installer works fine, and I can run installed *.exe files. However, when I check on Programs and Features, there is only 1 "big program" contain the size of MSI1, MSI2 and .Net4.5.1 (event .Net 4.5.1 installed before). When I uninstall this program, MSI1 and MSI2 are removed.

How can I install and uninstall separately each element in the Chain but still using Burn?

Hope this make sense.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might actually want this behavior, once you understand it.

Burn is a package manager. A package is installed by one or more bundles. When a bundle is uninstalled, any unneeded packages are uninstalled, too.

With default settings, bundles, but not MSIs installed by them, are shown in Programs and Features.

You can set `Visible="yes"` on an MsiPackage to have it shown in Programs and Features.

You can hide a Bundle from Programs and Features by setting `DisableRemove="yes" DisableModify="yes"`.

Comment: If you do this, you will be able to see the MSI's entry in ARP but when you uninstall the MSI manually and then again run the bundle's exe file, still it will prompt you to uninstall or repair, even though the exe is not visible in ARP. Not sure how to overcome this problem..

Comment: That's a feature. Even if all of the bundle packages are uninstalled the bundle is still installed so you need to be able to uninstall it (or repair it from the damage caused by someone uninstalling something without knowing what was dependent on it).